# Help with running C programs in Ubuntu

Tags: programming, c, ide

I've been teaching myself to write programs in C, using Geany as my IDE.

All of my programs get compiled and linked correctly, and they seem to work fine when I test run them inside of the IDE, however I can't seem to run to program without the use of the IDE.

I've tried using the terminal command `./[filename]`

However, I always get this response from the terminal:

```
bash: ./variabletest: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? Simply clicking on the executable's icon doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./variabletest` requires the file you are running to be in the current directory. Run `ls` and see if variabletest is displayed, if not, `cd` to the directory where it is stored the run the program from there. If you are not sure where your file is located, run

> `readlink -f (nameoffile here)`.

This command will show you the path to your file for example you can have

> /var/www/nameoffile

as the output. You the need to

> cd  /var/www

then run your programme from there.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, though I'm not certain how to implement it. I apologize but I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: @Clark, i have edited with the intention of shedding more light